# Push notification whenever a new document added into firestore collection?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a Collection into firestore and in that I have 3 documents with fields. and I am retrieving those documents in my app into recycler-View format. Now I was thinking to add some-type of functionality in my app like whenever new document Inserted into firestore collection a push notification get triggered to all the users "That new document get added". In every condition like whether app is in foreground or background state. How to do it?

Here is some code of mine:

```
mFirestore.collection("Banner").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error : " + e.getMessage());
                }
                assert documentSnapshots != null;

                for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        String doc_id = doc.getDocument().getId();
                        Banner banner = doc.getDocument().toObject(Banner.class).withDocId(doc_id);
                        bannerList.add(doc.getNewIndex(), banner);
                        sliderImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } else if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED) {
                        String docID = doc.getDocument().getId();
                        Banner changedModel = doc.getDocument().toObject(Banner.class).withDocId(docID);
                        if (doc.getOldIndex() == doc.getNewIndex()) {
                            // Item changed but remained in same position
                            bannerList.set(doc.getOldIndex(), changedModel);
                        } else {
                            // Item changed and changed position
                            bannerList.remove(doc.getOldIndex());
                            bannerList.add(doc.getNewIndex(), changedModel);
                        }
                    } else if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED) {
                        // remove
                        bannerList.remove(doc.getOldIndex());
                    }
                    sliderImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help u!

```
   firebaseFirestore.collection("your collection")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        switch (dc.getType()) {
                            case ADDED:
                                Uri new_defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                                NotificationCompat.Builder new_builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), "My Notification");
                                new_builder.setContentTitle("New Report added!");
                                new_builder.setContentText(dc.getDocument().getString("description"));
                                new_builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app);
                                new_builder.setSound(new_defaultSoundUri);
                                new_builder.setAutoCancel(true);

                                NotificationManagerCompat new_managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
                                new_managerCompat.notify(1, new_builder.build());
                                break;
                            case MODIFIED:
                                Uri modified_defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                                NotificationCompat.Builder modified_builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), "My Notification");
                                modified_builder.setContentTitle("New Report modified!");
                                modified_builder.setContentText(dc.getDocument().getString("description"));
                                modified_builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app);
                                modified_builder.setSound(modified_defaultSoundUri);
                                modified_builder.setAutoCancel(true);

                                NotificationManagerCompat modified_managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
                                modified_managerCompat.notify(2, modified_builder.build());
                                break;
                            case REMOVED:
                                Uri removed_defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                                NotificationCompat.Builder removed_builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), "My Notification");
                                removed_builder.setContentTitle("New Report modified!");
                                removed_builder.setContentText(dc.getDocument().getString("description"));
                                removed_builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app);
                                removed_builder.setSound(removed_defaultSoundUri);
                                removed_builder.setAutoCancel(true);

                                NotificationManagerCompat removed_managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
                                removed_managerCompat.notify(3, removed_builder.build());
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
```